# how to access the instance variables at class level in Python?

Tags: python

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
    
    if self.name== "xyz":
          print("Hi", self.name)
```

Here am getting an error - 'unresolved reference 'self'.

Can't we access the instance variables at the class level using `self`?

Comment: Code running at class level isn't connected to an instance; it runs before any instances are ever created.

Comment: No, we can't. You're trying to access an instance attribute when the _class_ isn't fully defined yet, yet alone any instances of it created.

Comment: No. A class could have zero to millions of instances. Which instance would it pick?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `if self.name== "xyz":`, what do you think `self` should be? Why? Did you want for this code to happen **during the `__init__` method**? Then that is a simple typo: think carefully about how the code is indented. Otherwise, I can't understand how you intend for this to work. Make sure you understand what a class **is**, and *what classes are for*.

Comment: Any code in a class that isn't in a method definition is executed when the class is being defined, before any instances are created. So there's no `self` yet.

Comment: Thanks to you all for providing answers. Appreciate the help! I have a follow up Q on same.. If I want to access the instance variables of a class within the class, can I do it only using instance methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instance variable `self.name` is created when a class instance is created, is unique to the instance and is destroyed when the instance is being deleted. Any given class could have 0 to many millions of unique instances active at the same time. If you could somehow reference one of the instances, which would it choose?

During the definition of the class as in your example, there are 0 instances. In fact the class object itself has not been fully constructed and has not been assigned to the name `A`. So you couldn't get an instance with a `self` variable even if you wanted to.

You've only defined how an instance with a `name` variable would be created, you haven't actually created one.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to access the instance variables. The first is to access it directly in the constructor, which is fairly obvious. The second method is to keep track of all instances of the class, and then iterate through them and access the specific variable of each instance that you are interested in.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, name_):
        self.name = name_
        if self.name == "xyz":
            print("Hi", self.name)

class B():
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, name_):
        self.name = name_
        self.instances.append(self)

a = A("xyz")
b = B("xyz")

for instance in B.instances:
    if instance.name == "xyz":
            print("Hi", instance.name)
```

Output:

```
Hi xyz
Hi xyz
```